# Django MultipleChoiceField with large set of objects (around 100000)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model with ManyToManyField:

```
class WordList(models.Model):
    words = models.ManyToManyField('Word')
```

These `WordList` objects should be created from admin, by choosing words (The size of `WordList` can be different, but, in general, there are should be around 10-20 words in every `WordList`) By default, Django admin use `MultipleChoiceField` to render control for `ManyToMany` field.

There are two problems with it.

1. The number of `Word` objects is around **100000**, and when I try to edit the `WordList` object in admin - it takes about 10 seconds on my dev server to load the page. Obviously, almost all time is taken by SELECT * FROM "app_word". That is bad, I am  want to speed up it at least to 1-3 seconds.
2. This is mostly design problem, but the issue reason connected with such large amount of objects. It is hard to find a `Word` in a drop-down list. I am tried to use [django-easy-select2][https://github.com/asyncee/django-easy-select2] which uses select2.js to add search to ModelChoiceField, but it works really slow and browser starting to eat all RAM and CPU.

Please help. Thank you.

P.S. I am using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Please try this widget: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal.

According to the doc:

> By default, a ManyToManyField is displayed in the admin site with a
>   **select multiple**. However, multiple-select boxes can be difficult to
>   use when selecting many items. Adding a ManyToManyField to this list
>   will instead use a nifty unobtrusive JavaScript “filter” interface
>   that allows searching within the options.

In your code you would do this:

```
class WordListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('words',)
```

Comment: Also, I'm suspecting that it's your browser not your server that take that much time to load the data. Loading 10k things in a dropdown takes time.